# I am trying to save editText into SQLite table, but when i click on button "addFavorites" nothing saved

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Here is my class which first show the item data from SQLite table into `EditText`, after that i am trying to save these `EditText` data to Favorites table by clicking on `addFavorites` button but nothing is saved kindy help

Here is the code :

```
public class ItemListDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText catID , itemID , itemName , itemDescription, unit , price ;
    Button addFavorites;
    DBhelper dBhelper;
    //int fav;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list_detail);

        dBhelper = new DBhelper(this);


        catID = findViewById(R.id.edCID);
        itemID = findViewById(R.id.edIID);
        itemName = findViewById(R.id.edName);
        itemDescription = findViewById(R.id.edDescription);
        unit = findViewById(R.id.edUnit);
        price = findViewById(R.id.edPrice);


        Items item = (Items) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("ITEMS");
       // fav = Integer.parseInt(item.getItemId());
        //fav = item.getItemId();

        catID.setText("CategoryID : " + item.getCategoryId());
        itemID.setText("ItemID : " +item.getItemId());
        itemName.setText("ItemName : " +item.getItemName());
        itemDescription.setText("Description : " +item.getItemDescription());
        unit.setText("Unit : " +item.getUnit());
        price.setText("Price : " +item.getPrice());


    }


       public void saveFavorites(View view) {
            String iID = itemID.getText().toString();
            String fID = itemID.getText().toString();

            Fav fav = new Fav(iID ,fID);
            int result =dBhelper.saveFavorites(fav);
            if(result > 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Favorites Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.bhb.vu_mcs.ItemListDetail">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addFavorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Add Favorites"
        android:onClick="saveFavorites"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edIID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edCID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edUnit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />



</LinearLayout>
```

package com.example.bhb.vu_mcs;

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by bhb on 1/30/2018.
 */

public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String KEY_CAT_TABLE = "CATEGORY";
    private static final String KEY_CAT_ID = "categoryId";
    private static final String KEY_CAT_NAME = "categoryName";
    private static final String KEY_CAT_DESCRIPTION = "categoryDescription";
    private static final String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + KEY_CAT_TABLE + "( "+ KEY_CAT_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_CAT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_CAT_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL )";


    private static final String KEY_ITEM_TABLE = "ITEMS";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_ID = "itemId";
    // private static final String COL3 = "categoryId";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_NAME = "itemName";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION = "itemDescription";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_UNIT = "unit";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + KEY_ITEM_TABLE + "( "+ KEY_ITEM_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_CAT_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_ITEM_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_ITEM_UNIT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_ITEM_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL )";



////////////this part is for favrities/////////////////////
    private static final String KEY_FAVORITES_TABLE = "FAVORITES";
    private static final String KEY_FAVORITES_ID = "favritesId";

    private static final String CREATE_FAVORITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + KEY_FAVORITES_TABLE + "( "+ KEY_FAVORITES_ID  + " INTEGER TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_ITEM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )";

///////////////////////


    public DBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_FAVORITES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KEY_CAT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KEY_ITEM_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KEY_FAVORITES_TABLE);
        onCreate( db);
    }

    public List<Items> getItemsForCategory(int catID) {
        List<Items> myitems  = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + KEY_ITEM_TABLE + " WHERE  categoryId = " + catID , null);
        if(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            do{
                String itemId = cursor.getString(0);
                String categoryId  = cursor.getString(1);
                String itemName = cursor.getString(2);
                String itemDescription = cursor.getString(3);
                String unit = cursor.getString(4);
                String price = cursor.getString(5);

                Items items = new Items(itemId, categoryId, itemName, itemDescription, unit, price);
                myitems.add(items);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return myitems;
    }

    public List<Fav> getFavorities() {
        List<Fav> myFav = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + KEY_FAVORITES_TABLE, null );
        if(cursor.moveToNext()){
            do{
                String fid = cursor.getString(0);
                String iid = cursor.getString(1);
                Fav favrities = new Fav(fid , iid);
                myFav.add(favrities);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return myFav;
    }

    public int saveFavorites(Fav fav) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_ID , fav.getItemId());
        values.put(KEY_FAVORITES_ID , fav.favId);
        //return db.update("FAVORITES" , values, "id=?", new String[]{fav.getItemId()} );
        long temp = db.insert("FAVORITES" , null, values);
        db.close();

       return (int) temp;


    }
}
```

Comment: post your DataBase helper class

Comment: where you are calling savefavourites function?

Comment: Post your `XML` file too.

Comment: how attach extra file to my question like xml and DB file

Comment: DataBAse Helper class and xml is added now kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do this. Use getWritableDatabase() instead of getReadableDatabase().

```
public int saveFavorites(Fav fav) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ITEM_ID , fav.getItemId());
    values.put(KEY_FAVORITES_ID , fav.favId);
   //return db.update("FAVORITES" , values, "id=?", new String[]{fav.getItemId()} );
    long temp = db.insert("FAVORITES" , null, values);
    db.close();

return (int) temp;


}
```

Comment: getReadableDatabase will, except in rare circumstances, get a writeable database. [getReadableDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getReadableDatabase%28%29). It's more like saying get a writeable database unless the only option is to get a read-only database. Whilst getWriteableDatabase would not return a read-only database. As such this wouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you issue is that you are either

- (a) trying to insert a string value that cannot be converted to an integer into a column that can only hold an integer or
- (b) trying to insert the same value into a column that must have unique values.

Without knowing the actual values which cannot be determined.

In SQLite any column can hold any type of value with ONE EXCEPTION and that is a column that is an alias of **rowid**. **rowid** being a special hidden column that exists by default (`WITHOUT ROWID` can be used to specify a table that has no rowid). A column with the special keywords `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (or appended with `AUTOINCREMENT`) is an alias of **rowid**.  Such a column can only be inserted with no value specified or an integer and the value must be unique.

So specifically the `KEY_ITEM_ID` (itemId) column of the FAVOURITES table as may be derived from `String fID = itemID.getText().toString();` cannot be anything other than a string that equates to an integer (perhaps it does). Furthermore, the value has to be unique.

It would appear that the `KEY_ITEM_ID` (itemId) is to reference the Item in the ITEMS table. As such you should probably just specify `INTEGER` or perhaps `INTEGER NOT NULL` as the column type.

Although not really an issue the `KEY_FAVORITES_ID` (favritesId) column is defined as `INTEGER TEXT NOT NULL`, you should probably change this to `INTEGER NOT NULL`.

As such I believe you should change :-

```
private static final String CREATE_FAVORITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + KEY_FAVORITES_TABLE + "( "+ KEY_FAVORITES_ID  + " INTEGER TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_ITEM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )";
```

to be :-

```
private static final String CREATE_FAVORITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + KEY_FAVORITES_TABLE + "( "+ KEY_FAVORITES_ID  + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_ITEM_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL )";
```

Note! to implement the above you will need to DROP and recreate the FAVOURITES. If losing all data is not an issue, then you could do one of the following;

- (a) uninstall the App,
- (b) delete the App's data or
- (c) increase the version number.